# How to say the plural of IP?

Tags: grammatical-number, acronyms

Can someone assist me with this doubt? In many sites I have seen it written as "IP's" and in other as "IPs".
What is the correct form to refer for the plural of IP?

Comment: You can *say* it either way. Both sound exactly the same. As to *writing* it, see the linked question. Executive summary: no apostrophe.

Comment: I would pronounce the names of the letters: /ay'pi/ and /ay'piz/. For writing, there are no rules since `IP` has no history. Anyway, nobody cares whether you use an apostrophe or not, so why bother? Apostrophes are **so** pre-electronic tech.

Comment: Assuming you're taking about intonational phrases, the the standard format they use in academic writing is IPs. HTH!

Answer (score 2):

My instinct would be to use "IPs" as adding an apostrophe implies either a contraction or ownership. This would probably be better asked in https://english.stackexchange.com/, though

Comment: I was going to ask down there, but as this site is focused to that theme, I decided to ask it here.

Comment: @tachomi: The next time, please check the [help]. This is *entirely* [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)  here and [english.se] is the only acceptable site for it.

Comment: Ok then.... I'm not able to delete the question and put it on the right site :( ... sorry for this. By the way, thanks a lot @John

Comment: @SvW But it is a linguistics abbreviation though that we would know about and ELL wouldn't ...